# How to use ssh key with gulp-rsync and cygwin

Tags: windows, ssh, gulp, cygwin

I am using a gulp task to deploy my application, like this (in this example I am omitting the real values)

```
gulp.task('deploy', function () {
return gulp.src(config.deployFiles)
        .pipe(rsync({
            root: 'build/',
            hostname: 'hostname',
            username: 'username',
            destination: 'destination'
     }));});
```

However,the command fails with

gulp-rsync: Permission denied (publickey).

Note: I can access the remote server through ssh, the point is how to tell cygwin to use the right ssh key so that gulp-rsync can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I found so far. In a cygwin terminal run

```
ssh-host-config
```

it will create a config file into the cygwin/etc folder (/etc/ssh_config). Then, add to that file a host entry

```
  Host hostnameToUse
       Hostname xx.xx.xx.xx.xx
       Port 22
       IdentityFile D:\keys\vps
```

Then update the hostname in the gulp task to 'hostnameToUse'
gulp deploy works:

gulp-rsync: sending incremental file list....

Answer (score 2):

You are right @ojb. I also got stuck in a similar position when I wanted to push my production ready code online using gulp as a part of my automated workflow.

Basically there is no standard parameter to pass as  ssh_key_location in `gulp-rsync`. So a workaround is to use ssh config file to create a local *pseudo host name*. This process masks the *actual host name* with a *pseudo host name*.

> (ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com + **key**) =>
>   hostname.com

Since there is no proper documentation on how to resolve this here is a detailed-how-to for everyone who might face this issue

**First Step:** Update ~/.ssh/config file to make this working: `$ ssh hostname.com`

```
Host hostname.com
    HostName ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    User ec2-user
    IdentityFile ~/<path-to-file>/keyfile.pem
```

**Second Step:**

Add this to your gulp function

```
  // Dirs and Files to sync
  rsyncPaths = ['directory-names', './file-name',....];
  // Default options for rsync
  rsyncConf = {
    progress: true,
    incremental: true,
    relative: true,
    emptyDirectories: true,
    recursive: true,
    clean: true,
    exclude: [],
  };
```

**Third Step:** Create following function in gulp

```
//something-on-top    
return gulp.src(rsyncPaths)
   .pipe($.rsync(rsyncConf));
```

**Troubleshoot:**
 1. Check if the file has 400 access rights
 2. Check if `$ ssh hostname.com` works or not

Answer (score 0):

Just recently came into this issue and managed to put it together. Since no one else on the web posted a solution, figured I'd do my duty here and pass it along. Hope it can still be useful to others:

**gulp-rsync** doesn't support this by default, but back in 2015  there was an added feature for any custom options when running the command (https://github.com/jerrysu/gulp-rsync/issues/17). You can attach the `-e` option to your shell command like so:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rsync = require('gulp-rsync');

gulp.task('deploy', function() {
  gulp.src('build/**')
    .pipe(rsync({
      username: 'user',
      hostname: 'host',
      destination: '~/',

      options: {
        "e": "ssh -i <local-path-to-key-file>"
      }

    }));
});
```